# VSCode cannot find pipenv: spawn pipenv ENOENT

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

Pipenv is installed as I can run

```
$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2018.11.26
```

However, with a project folder open in VSCode containing a `Pipfile`, VSCode complains:

```
Workspace contains pipfile but attempt to run 'pipenv --venv' failed
with 'spawn pipenv ENOENT'. Make sure pipenv is on the PATH
```

Answer (score 6):

On your user settings (or workspace settings) set:

```
"python.pipenvPath": "/path/to/pipenv"
```

You must do this explicitly even though Pipenv is in your `PATH` properly. See [vscode-python#2139](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2139) which motivated the reason to add `python.pipenvPath` to settings.